# Get Audio File URLS from archive.org using json

Tags: javascript, html, json, archive

Archive.org json doc: http://archive.org/help/json.php

I am using this url: https://archive.org/metadata/AhmedAlajmiTheCompleteHolyQuran

The json format is displayed in this order

036.mp3

016.mp3

However the actual order on the details page is

001.mp3

002.mp3

The details page: https://archive.org/details/AhmedAlajmiTheCompleteHolyQuran

How can i get the uploaders sorted order that is displayed in the details page. How come the json is sorted in a different format. I can sort the urls based on the numbers, but the file name will not always be by numbers.

This is what i have so far. It just gets the mp3 urls. BUT THE ORDER IS WRONG!

```
var urlJ = "https://archive.org/metadata/AhmedAlajmiTheCompleteHolyQuran";
function functionName() {
var url = "https://archive.org/metadata/AhmedAlajmiTheCompleteHolyQuran";
var details = "https://archive.org/download/AhmedAlajmiTheCompleteHolyQuran";
function jsonpCallback(response) {
    //after success some staff
    var files = response.files;
    for(var i=0; i < files.length; i++){
        if(files[i].source == "original"){
            console.log(details + "/" + files[i].name);
        }
    }
    console.log(response.files[0]);
}

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        alert(error.message);
    },
    success: jsonpCallback
});
return false;
}
functionName();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to sort it with the API provided, however the metadata provides one piece of data you can use to sort it yourself.

[mtime](http://fileformats.archiveteam.org/wiki/Internet_Archive_metadata) - Unix-style timestamp of file

Therefore, you can just sort it with JavaScript (put this right after you pull response.files):

```
var files = response.files;

for (var i = files.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            if (typeof files[i].mtime === 'undefined')
                files.splice(i, 1);

files.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.mtime - b.mtime;
});
```

Also, if you're only pulling the files, you can just request only the files with:

```
https://archive.org/metadata/AhmedAlajmiTheCompleteHolyQuran/files
```

When I run the code:

> [image]

Comment: it doesn't sort it based on 001 002, i guess there is not api provided . i thought i was just missing something

Comment: When I run that sorting function, I get `001.ogg`, `002.ogg`, in that order. It's sorted based on mtime, which is a reliable timestamp, are you not getting the order you want?

Comment: no for some reason no change . check my temp webpage
http://template.webdvlm.com/content/index_inline.php

Comment: its awesome if you can show me how to get the correct order

Comment: @WebDevelopment Within the array, there were missing mtimes, copy the code from my answer again, it should work.

Comment: the missing mtimes were not effecting the sort, check the link again, its still doesn't sort. You can see from the source that i copied the code exactly

http://template.webdvlm.com/content/index_inline.php

Comment: @WebDevelopment You have to use `a.mtime - b.mtime`, **not** `a.name - b.name`.